# Trying to ngFor a class of a class

Tags: angular5

I am unable to ngFor a class: here is the live code I am working on:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-62alpm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
   export class Data{

   public data: types;
 }

@Injectable()
   export class types{

   public numb1: number;
   public numb2: number;
   public numb3: number;
   public numb4: number;
 }
```

code:

```
//works
<div>
  {{_types.data.numb1}}
  {{_types.data.numb2}}
  {{_types.data.numb3}}
  {{_types.data.numb4}}
</div>
```

produce (expectation with ngfor - need same result without changing the class structure):

```
 2
 3
 5
 7
```

Here I am trying to produce same thing with ngfor ... does not work

```
<div *ngFor="let test of _types.data">
  {{test}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to loop over an element with ngFor, your element has to be an Array. I suggest you to change your types class by this :

```
@Injectable()
   export class types{

   public numbers: Array<number> = [];
 }
```

then in numbers you push your 4 numbers (numb1, numb2, numb3, numb4)

And then you can iterate over it like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let test of _types.data.numbers">
  {{test}}
</div>
```

Comment: Okay thank you, also is there a way to iterate over 2 array at the same time ? data.numbers and data.message for example.

so it would display as {{numbers}} : {{message}}